# Read multiple integer lines from a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

```
4
1 2 4 3 5 4 5
4 1 7 3 3
2 1 3 4 10
```

The first line is number of vertices.

From second line, first column, is the vertex. Next set of 'pairs' are vertex and weight respectively.

I tried just to read only first line using `fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", vertices);` which gave garbage value. `vertices = fgetc(fptr);` gave me a different value but not garbage (I think)

The second line onwards, I'm not sure how to add to my adj list directed graph, but I need help just to get those values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("adjacencylist.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) exit(1);

    int vertices, c;
    //fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", vertices);
    //vertices = fgetc(fptr);
    vertices = fgetc(fptr);
    printf("%d", vertices);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: The *code* you wrote is imperative to tell you where things went wrong and how to correct them. Things like `fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", vertices);` "which gave garbage" means *nothing* without a proper [mcve] to allow us to see *why* that seemed to happen. Update your question with a proper reproduction that we can compile and test as you have.

Comment: I put up the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you're processing is per-line (save for the first value read, which technically is just a counter, but still resides on its own line). That means you need a strategy for processing data line at a time. You also need to facilitate moving a "cursor" (really just an offset) through the line as you extract vertex+weight pairs.

One way to do this is using [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) (part of POSIX) for reading the lines dynamically, then using `sscanf` to extract the values, and in particular using the `%n` added format specifier to track how many characters were consumed in the last formatted read. This feature will allow you to advance a next-read-from position in the line buffer so as to track where to get the next pair of vertex+weight.

If you don't have access to  POSIX `getline` you could always (a) write your own, or (b) just use a sufficiently sized line buffer to ensure complete capture of your longest line. But not going to lie; having `getline` makes it a ton easier.

Anyway..

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // open the file
    FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read the first counter of vertices
    int n = 0;
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0)
    {
        // TODO setup your vesticies here using 'n'
        printf("%d verticies will be used\n", n);

        // skip to end of line
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n');

        // read one line at a time
        char *line = NULL;      // dynamic line pointer
        size_t len = 0;         // length of last line-read

        while (getline(&line, &len, fp) > 0)
        {
            char *cur = line;   // current line position
            int ccs = 0;        // no. of chars read on last scan
            int v1;             // beginning vertex of each line

            // extract the vertex number
            if (sscanf(cur, "%d%n", &v1, &ccs) == 1)
            {
                printf("v1(%d) : ", v1);

                // advance line position past data-just-read
                cur += ccs;

                // read second vertex and weight as pairs
                int v2;
                int w;
                while (sscanf(cur, "%d %d%n", &v2, &w, &ccs) == 2)
                {
                    // TODO: setup the [v1,v2] = w relationship here
                    printf("(%d,%d) ", v2, w);

                    // advance cursor past data just-read
                    cur += ccs;
                }

                fputc('\n', stdout);
            }
        }

        // release whatever buffer we managed
        free(line);
    }

    // close the file before continuing the program
    fclose(fp);

    // TODO: use your data here

    return 0;
}
```

Run against your input data, the output is:

```
4 vertices will be used
v1(1) : (2,4) (3,5) (4,5) 
v1(4) : (1,7) (3,3) 
v1(2) : (1,3) (4,10)
```

See here for the specific of the [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) family of functions, and note particularly the use of `%n` in the code above. Its ability to reap how many characters were just processed, and thus how to advance `cur` to the next read position of the line buffer, is critical to how the above works.

Comment: I'll take time to understand this code, I'll ask if I have any doubt. Thanks a lot, I learnt quite a lot just from this.